# How to drop a single model in Django, and leave the others

Tags: django, django-migrations, django-1.9

I have 4 models. I want to redo 1 one of them that I've been working on. The other 3 models have user data that I don't want to lose.

I want to entirely drop one table, and sync it up with what's in models.py.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could remove the model from `models.py`, and create a migration which will drop the table.

```
./manage.py makemigrations
```

Then add the model back to your `models.py`, and create a new migration which will recreate the model.

```
./manage.py makemigrations
```

Finally, run your migrations and you should be done.

```
./manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear what you want to do here.

You can write new model class and delete old model class that you want to remove. After that run migrations the normal way.
It will delete the table related to deleted model class and make whatever othe changes you have defined in the models.